# Build Error when run Resharper InspectCode Command Line

Tags: windows-phone-8, msbuild, resharper

i have a windows phone 8 application and i want to run resharper inspect code from command line.
I have downloaded resharper command line tool from chocolatey, and installed it. But when i run the inspect code tool, there is an error like this :
***'Building Windows Phone application using MSBuild 64bit is not supported'.***

How to solve it? I have tried add /p:PlatformTarget=x86 and still error.

Thank you